# IOS UINavigationItem edit button at runtime issues

Tags: ios, cocoa

i am trying to edit a Button in a NavigationBar based on user input, i need to change the action the button points to, and the title.

It seems like i cant do this at runetime.

CalendarMonthViewParent.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalendarMonthViewParent : UIViewController

-(void) callChildChange; // This is called from another viewController, telling it to change the button

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *skemaNavigationItem; // this is the Navigation Item in the Storyboard, it has no right btn by default

@end
```

CalendarMonthViewParent.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // on viewDidLoad i set up the button with an action, via the outlet, this works fine

    UINavigationItem *thisNavBar = [self skemaNavigationItem];

    UIBarButtonItem *insertBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Indsæt" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(insertSkemaItem:)];

    thisNavBar.rightBarButtonItem = insertBtn;

}


- (void)callChildChange {

...

// this method is called from another view controller, based on some user input
// this method is supposed to change the button

UINavigationItem *thisNavBar = [self skemaNavigationItem];

// i fetch the button like i did it in viewDidLoad, but i cannot preform operations on it here

// thisNavBar is nil when called here, but it is not nil when called in viewDidLoad?

...
}
```

If my aproach is incorrect and impossible, i would appreciate any solution that would work

**EDIT:** 
My UIViewController, is NOT inside a UINavigationController, i am just using the UINavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` already has a property `navigationItem` which is automatically used when the view controller is in a navigation controller, so it seems unlikely that `skemaNavigationItem` is being used. The code for creating and setting the bar button item looks ok (other than where it is being set to). If you want to edit the bar button item you need to create and set a new one, don't actually try to edit the existing one.

---

If `skemaNavigationItem` is nil then either you haven't connected the outlet or you're calling the controller at the wrong time (before the view has been loaded - this could be because you are creating a new view controller instead of using the existing on on screen).

Comment: One comment, i am not using a NavigationController, i just wanted the top-bar, so i am setting it like this

Comment: Ok, so you could use the built in navigation item (and add it to the navigation bar in code) or your one in the XIB.

Comment: The weird thing is that i am setting thisNavBar the same way as i am setting it in viewDidLoad, UINavigationItem *thisNavBar = [self skemaNavigationItem]; and its in the same ViewController, the only difference is that the first method is viewDidLoad and the other method is called from another viewController

Comment: How you are calling from another view controller (or, rather, how you are getting the instance to call) could be the problem...